# Get request url from instance aws beanstalk with route53

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

my site is in aws (route53, certificate manager, load balance and the backend in spring with thymeleaf in Beanstalk)
need get the request url from springboot app, this's my code:

```
@RequestMapping("/categoria/{permalink}")
    public ModelAndView articlesByCategory(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("articles-by-category");
        model.addObject("siteName", getSiteName(httpServletRequest));
        return model;
}
```

```
 private String getSiteName(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        String url = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
        if (url.contains("www.mysite.com"))
            return "Sitename 1";
        if (url.contains("www.mysite3.com"))
            return "Sitename 3";
        return "Site name group";

    }
```

but in instance aws the returned value is 127.0.0.1 or the private IP... cannot get [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com).

Any ideas how to get the request url?